# Error accessing Jar Manifest for file

Tags: java, eclipse, web

I have created a dynamic web project in Eclipse, but when I set up the server and deploy it, the server always reports a warning level message in the log stating

> Error accessing Jar Manifest for file .../WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF: file does not exist!

but the application is running fine! Why does this warning appear? What does it mean and how can I avoid id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means exactly what it says, that there is no manifest file under that path.

The manifest file is used by the application to figure out all kind of things, mainly required libraries in the classpath.

In order to solve this, just go to Webcontent/META-INF and create a MANIFEST.MF file with these lines:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path:
```